# Is "otherwise else" correct?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, redundancy

I have a friend who uses the term "otherwise else" regularly. She frequently uses words incorrectly and pronounces some things in a dialect all her own, so at first I didn't think much of it. The more she uses it, the more I'm bothered by it. I'm wondering if it has an odd sound because I don't hear it often or if it is incorrect.
*Examples:*

> 1. I need an answer to this question! Otherwise else I'm going to be confused for eternity!
> 2. I need to run this errand after work, otherwise else I won't have time until the weekend.
> 3. I need to write in pencil, otherwise else I'll use a whole tube of white out.
> 4. You have to seal the cheese completely, otherwise else it will dry out.

Comment: How about adding a couple of examples?

Comment: This reads more like a complaint than a question, because I think you know the answer... I think user3169 is asking for examples which your friend uses, not examples you have made up.

Comment: We will need some complete sentences, at the least, otherwise else we probably can't provide good answers. Seriously, though  it is not a construction that **I** have heard myself or another native speaker ever say; but I haven't heard all the things that native speakers say which some people consider grammatical. I would never use it, except in fun, as in my first sentence. Just choose between the two words: you don't need both.

Comment: More examples added.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I was thinking it seemed a bit redundant as well. Sometimes things just sound odd but are perfectly acceptable. I was just wondering if this was one of these things or if it's grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @Whitney Redundancy is not a crime in attempting to communicate. But no native speaker I know says those two words in succession. It's not so much a matter of redundancy but of *not being idiomatic.* But even native speakers will sometimes grab onto a pet phrase that no one else thinks is grammatical yet they  won't give it up. Usually I'll take successful communication over perfect English any day.

Comment: @Whitney This is a midwesternism, in the lexicon along with _also too_ and my favorite: _and but._ Your friend should be taken out in the soybean fields and sprayed with Roundup.

Comment: I suppose for future reference, please provide [more details](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).  Specifically, if you have questions about what your friends say, it would be helpful if we knew where they were from and what kind of English they use (eg. American, British, etc). Examples would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more correct say either: "otherwise" on its own, or "or else", so the following would be better constructed sentences:

> I need an answer to this question! Otherwise I'm going to be confused for eternity!
>
> I need an answer to this question! Or else I'm going to be confused for eternity!

Saying "otherwise else" is a tautology and sounds a bit jarring to me, though the meaning is perfectly clear.

Comment: Why "or else"? Why not just "else"?

Comment: Might be a UK/US variation but `or else` I wouldn't be surprised to hear. Grammar pedants might argue that you can't use "or else" if you have an exclamation mark after "question".